# Unity3D: How does Spectator View work through user side of Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, mr-spectatorview

I am having a hard time understanding the documentation. So I trying to spectate using a Hololens mounted on a camera. The user Hololens has an application. What do I need to do on the user side Hololens to enable Spectator View? Does it require MRTK? What components do I need to add to make on the Unity3D application (user side) to make it visible by the Spectator Hololens

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/mixed-reality/spectator-view .. this is not related to Unity but a question for the Microsoft-Support ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to do on the user side Hololens to enable Spectator View? Does it require MRTK?

First, you need to go through the [Getting Started](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView#getting-started) to obtain and reference the MixedReality-SpectatorView codebase in your project.

Then, add the `MixedReality.SpectatorView/SpectatorView/Prefabs/SpectatorView.prefab` to the primary scene and choose a Spatial Alignment Strategy, following [Basic Unity Setup](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView#basic-unity-setup) for step-by-step tutorial.

For Video camera rig HoloLens, you need to calibrate and test your device according to this document: [Spectator View Video Camera Setup](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/blob/master/doc/SpectatorView.Setup.VideoCamera.md).

After that, the PC listens to pose updates from video camera rig hololens and gets scene information from the user HoloLens, then composites this application content into the video camera stream.

Besides, MRTK as an SDK is intended to accelerate the development of MR projects and is not required to enable SpectatorView.

Comment: Thanks! So, I followed these steps! But I'm not sure how to generate builds separately for the Spectator Hololens and for user Hololens? and I didnt find any scene with name `SpectatorView.HoloLens.Spectator.unity` mentioned in the 10th step of https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView#basic-unity-setup , although I found `SpectatorView.HoloLens.unity`